# formatting results of mysql_fetch_array() for use with array_diff()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to re-format / re-order the array results I'm getting from mysql_fetch_array() to give a much simpler array to work with.

At the moment when retrieving results from a DB I use a class that does this:

```
$return = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->query_result, MYSQL_NUM)) {            
    array_push($return, $row);
}
```

..this function outputs this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => Floral
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => Occasion
    )

)
```

somehow I want to actually output this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Floral
    [5] => Occasion
)
```

I cant get my head around it! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($return as $result){
        $final[$result[0]] = $result[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
foreach ($array as $value){
        $result[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
        $rows = array();
        $row = array();

        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

            while(list($field, $val) = each($fetch)){

                $row[$field] = $val;

            }//end while

            $rows[] = $row;

        }//end while

        return $rows;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, think I'll go with above though.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly what you need to do is this:

```
Array[ index ] = value;
```